# Matching lines in file from list

Tags: powershell

I have two text files, Text1.txt and Text2.txt

Text2.txt is a list of keywords, one keyword per line. I want to read from Text1.txt and any time a keyword in the Text2.txt list shows up, pipe that entire line of text to a new file, output.txt

Without using Text2.txt I figured out how to do it manually in PowerShell.

```
Get-Content .\Text1.txt | Where-Object {$_ -match 'CAPT'} | Set-Content output.txt
```

That seems to work, it searches for "CAPT" and returns the entire line of text, but I don't know how to replace the manual text search with a variable that pulls from Text2.txt

Any ideas?

Comment: How many keywords would you have typically? 10, 100, 1000?

Comment: Under 1,000 in Text2.txt. Text1 could be pretty huge though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using some simple regex you can make a alternative matching string from all the keywords in the file Text2.txt

```
$pattern = (Get-Content .\Text2.txt | ForEach-Object{[regex]::Escape($_)}) -Join "|"
Get-Content .\Text1.txt | Where-Object {$_ -match $pattern} | Set-Content output.txt
```

In case your keywords have special regex characters we need to be sure they are escaped here. The .net regex method `Escape()` handles that.

This is not an efficient approach for large files but it is certainly a simple method. If your keywords were all similar like CAPT CAPS CAPZ then we could improve it but I don't think it would be worth it depending how often the keywords change.

**Changing the pattern**

If you wanted to just match the first 4 characters from the lines in your input file that is just a matter of making a change in the loop.

```
$pattern = (Get-Content .\Text2.txt | ForEach-Object{[regex]::Escape($_.Substring(0,4))}) -Join "|"
```

Comment: Only problem is if the keywords include a `|` (or another regex character).

Comment: Thanks @Matt!  I didn't know about the `Escape()` method... :)

Comment: Question - it seems to be working, though I'm getting data I didn't expect. (Which isn't a problem with the script, it is the stupid data I have to use). Is there an easy way to make it only match against the first four characters of Text1.txt? (Still returning whole line of text into output.txt)

Comment: @WDavis I made a small update to account for that request.